# Using "Material Preview" HDRI in Renders?

Tags: rendering, eevee-render-engine, hdri

I know that I can use default HDRI maps in Rendered mode in Blender right now, but the problem is when I wan to render the image by F12 (or render movie), my settings are changed to use "scene world". Is there a hidden button somewhere in rendering tab or somewhere else? If I have HDRI correct in rendered mode, why I can't have the same result after <kbd>F12</kbd> render?

Comment: I must admit... I re read your question 20 times at least, and yet, I couldn't grasp what you are asking. What results are you getting when rendering ? Post your blend file, we will be able to answer, hopefully...

Comment: I think this is what you’re asking for https://youtu.be/eMKST_ddg6s check out 3:40

Comment: This is why I asked, because in viewport everything is correct (as it is in the video you posted), but after rendering, Blender ignores this setting, and uses node-based settings.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This is possible, but at the time of writing it's not a one click solution.

First you need to setup your world to use an environment texture and then load the same HDRI that is used in *Look Dev* mode. The HDRI can be setup either in the *World* tab or in the *Shader Editor* using nodes.

**Blender 2.80**

[image: World tab 2.80]
[image: Shader editor 2.80]

**Blender 2.81 and later**

[image: World tab 2.81]
[image: Shader editor 2.81]

The HDRIs can be found in Blender's installation directory:

```
[Install dir]/2.80/datafiles/studiolights/world
```

---

In Blender 2.81 you can use the same HDRI from *Material Preview* mode (formerly called *Look Dev*) for lighting in the *Rendered* preview mode in the viewport. Switch to the *Rendered* mode by clicking on its icon, then open the *Viewport Shading* options and disable *Scene World* to ignore the settings from the *World* tab. One of the HDRI presets can then be selected.

[image: Rendered Mode Viewport Shading]

However for the actual rendering you will still need to set it up as described above. In case you've already done that, the *Viewport Shading* options can be left at their default values with *Scene World* enabled.

Comment: I am using blender 2.81. This works, but how do I hide the hdri image in the background?

Comment: @MVTC In the *Render Properties* open the *Film* tab and check the *Transparent* option.