# Render light difficulties

Tags: rendering, light, eevee-render-engine

I've selected a nice light effect from `Viewport Shading` as seen in the image below:

[image]

But the actual render doesn't look like in the preview. It looks like this:

[image]

How to render the image like in the preview?

Comment: Perhaps this is what you want: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/158336/using-material-preview-hdri-in-renders-blender-2-81

Comment: Yes, that I was looking for. Thanks!