# How can I make my render looks like the one in viewport shading where I have scene light and world on?

Tags: rendering, 3d-view, eevee-render-engine, lighting

In my viewport shading I have scene lighting and scene world on, it looks great but when I render it out, it looks so dark like the scenes doesn't apply to the render.  Is there any way to make the render looks exactly the same as the viewport one ?
[image]

Comment: This is what the render img looks like : https://i.imgur.com/tWptNdW.png

Comment: This should help: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/158336/using-material-preview-hdri-in-renders-blender-2-81

Comment: I'll try it. Thanx alotttttt !!!