# Why does the viewport shading look way better then render view on both eevee and cycles

Tags: cycles-render-engine, 3d-view, eevee-render-engine

My model looks photorealistic in viewport shading, and cartoonish is render view how do I fix this from happening.

This is what it looks like in viewport shading
[image: Viewport shading]

And this is what it looks like in render view on both Eevee and cycles
[image: Rendered view]

Comment: Add in an HDRI sky. Your present lighting setup creates no shadows. Evee has a default HDRI that's reflecting in the glass I believe.

Comment: I do have an HDRI sky I'm not worried about the shadows at this point but mainly how the bottle looks like the blacktop where it actually looks like rubber and plastic on the viewport shading and just a black blob in the render view

Comment: Related for proper node setup: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/158336/using-material-preview-hdri-in-renders-blender-2-81

Comment: jachym- that just improved the viewport shading and did not affect render view. I just want my render view to look exactly like the viewport shading for now as a more photorealistic interpretation.