# How to get same Render as in Viewport (Eevee)

Tags: rendering, 3d-view, eevee-render-engine

There is similiar questions but I couldn't manage to get good answer.[image: Viewport]

1st Viewport screenshot

2nd Render in Eevee
They're both transparent don't mind that.

[image]

Tried tweaking World node as seen in one answer but couldn't get it right. Can't get inside of wheel, and especially balls, to look same.
In viewport shading Scene lights are on, Scene world is off with studiolighting

[image]

[image]

Comment: hello please share the file

Comment: I did, don't mind broken animation. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You need to reactivate your *Scene World* option in the *Viewport Shading* panel, otherwise it will be the *Material Preview* world that will been taken into account:

[image]

Comment: Thanks, tried that, but then my viewport is same as render. But I want my render to be like viewport. As seen on my first screenshot in my question.

Comment: In that case you need to use the same HDRI used in Material Preview, check this answer: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/158336/using-material-preview-hdri-in-renders#:~:text=In%20Blender%202.81%20you%20can,settings%20from%20the%20World%20tab.

Comment: Thank you. Now I see

Comment: Or, do a viewport render.