# How can I render without Scene World?

Tags: rendering

I'm trying to render exactly what I see in the viewport.

[image]

I have unchecked *Scene World* but it still renders with the scene world.  I'm trying to render the precise image I look at and I'm not quite sure how to do it.

Comment: maybe check this answer: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/158336/using-material-preview-hdri-in-renders

Comment: If you uncheck the *Scene World* checkbox then Blender uses a build-in HDRI instead of the settings in *World Properties* tab. It's the sphere that you see in the drop-down menu. If you click on it you can choose another and in the tooltip you can see its name. *Moonboots*' linked question shows how to use this HDRI in the *World Properties* for render.

Comment: hi, that answer helped.  it is still not exactly what I see, but it's a huge improvement and good enough that I can work with it.  Honestly, I wish it was a bit more intuitive here because that answer was pretty involved but there's no way I would have figured it out so thanks so much!!!

Answer (score 2):

Blender doesn't automatically use the 3D viewport HDRI in render mode. If you wish to use the “exact” same HDRI image in your actual render, you'll need to manually setup the HDRI in your scene’s world nodes by using a Environment node:

## World Nodes - Setup

[image]

## Environment Map - Path

Native HDRIs that ship with Blender can be found under:

```
\\Blender\%BLENDER_VERSION%\datafiles\studiolights\world\forest.exr
```

- `forest.exr` is the default HDRI used in the 3D Viewport, but you can use any of the HDRIs found in the Blender HDRI folder.
- You can also use one of your own HDRI images, if you wish.

Answer (score 2):

To render the viewport, goto: *3D Viewport > View (Menu) > Viewport Render Image*

[image: screenshot of menu item]

Answer (score -1):

You need to choose *Render > Film > Transparent*

Comment: In the post, this option is already enabled.